# Custom Django form submits properly locally but not on the server

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms

I'm completely stumped. I have a form that has been customized with some JS for interactivity. It's really pretty simple. And it works great locally. However, on the server, when the user uses the drop down select, the form won't submit.

I can't see anything that is causing this and it's driving me mad.

The live form is here: http://trainer.cbirt.org/events/test-event/sign-up/

The JS is not compressed right now so that I can troubleshoot this.

So far I've tried:

- blowing away and rebuilding the VE on the server
- placing the relevant js local to the file
- reworking how the js works seven ways to sunday

The only things I can think to do left are to host all the JS locally, but that makes NO sense why that would work because the submission is not based on the JS.

Any and all suggestions are welcome.

Form code:

```
{% extends "events/base.html" %}

{% block page_class %}full-screen{% endblock page_class %}

{% block content%}

<h1>Sign Up for {{ event.title }}</h1>

<ul class="instructions">
<li>Fill in your name and email address, and tell us if you are a Team member</li>
<li>Fill in the form that appears</li>
<li>Click Submit</li>
</ul>

{% if form.errors %}
    <ul class="errors">
        {% for error in form.errors %}
            {% if error == "first_name" %}
                <li>Please enter your <strong>first name</strong>.</li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if error == "last_name" %}
                <li>Please enter your <strong>last name</strong>.</li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if error == "email" %}
                <li>Please enter your <strong>email</strong>.</li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="" id="signup">

    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="form_block">
        <label for="id_first_name">First name:</label>
        <input id="id_first_name" type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" />
    </div>

    <div class="form_block">
        <label for="id_last_name">Last name:</label>
        <input id="id_last_name" type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" />
    </div>

    <div class="form_block">
        <label for="id_email">Email:</label>
        <input id="id_email" type="text" name="email" maxlength="75" />
    </div>

    <div class="form_block team_mem">
        <label for="id_tbi_team_member">Are you a TBI Team Member?</label>
        <div class="yes-no">
            <span class="yes">Yes</span>
            <span class="no">No</span>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="tbi_team_member" id="id_tbi_team_member" />
    </div>

    <section class="team-member">
        <div class="form_block">
            <label for="id_hotel_checkin_date">Hotel checkin date:</label>
            <input type="text" name="hotel_checkin_date" id="id_hotel_checkin_date" />
        </div>

        <div class="form_block">
            <label for="id_hotel_checkout_date">Hotel checkout date:</label>
            <input type="text" name="hotel_checkout_date" id="id_hotel_checkout_date" />
        </div>

        <div class="form_block">
            <label for="id_yes_share">Are you willing to share a room?</label>
            <div class="yes-no">
                <span class="yes">Yes</span>
                <span class="no">No</span>
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="yes_share" id="id_yes_share" />
        </div>

        <div class="form_block">
            <label for="id_share_suite">Are you willing to share a suite?</label>
            <div class="yes-no">
                <span class="yes">Yes</span>
                <span class="no">No</span>
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="share_suite" id="id_share_suite" />
        </div>

        <div class="form_block">
            <label for="id_team_dinner">Will you join us for the team dinner?</label>
            <div class="yes-no">
                <span class="yes">Yes</span>
                <span class="no">No</span>
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="team_dinner" id="id_team_dinner" />
        </div>

    </section>

    <section class="not-team-member">

        <div class="form_block">
            <h3>Price of training per day - $40</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="form_block">
            <label for="id_payment_method">Payment method:</label>
            <select name="payment_method" id="id_payment_method">
                <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
                <option value="2">Cash</option>
                <option value="3">Check</option>
                <option value="4">PO</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form_block">
            <h4>Cash and checks will be collected at the door.</h4>
        </div>

    </section>

    <section class="general">

        <div class="form_block">
            <label for="id_dietary_restrictions">Do you have dietary restrictions?</label>
            <input id="id_dietary_restrictions" type="text" name="dietary_restrictions" maxlength="200" />
        </div>

        <div class="form_block">
            {% if event.pdu %}
                <p>{{ event.pdu.content }}</p>
            {% endif %}
            {% if event.ceu %}
                <p>{{ event.ceu.content }}</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

        <div class="form_block">
            <label for="id_your_notes">Notes and special accommodations:</label>
            <textarea id="id_your_notes" rows="10" cols="40" name="your_notes"></textarea>
        </div>

    </section>

    <div class="form_block">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" id="event-signup" />
    </div>
</form>

{% endblock content %}

{% block addthis %}{% endblock addthis %}
```

And the JS

```
$('#id_payment_method').change(function(event) {
    //console.log($(this));
    $('option').each(function(event) {
        $('option:not(:selected)').attr('selected', false);
        $('option:selected').attr('selected', true);
    });
});
```

Comment: I added in the code for the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I can see there are fields hidden/displayed based on a radio box.

I would check to make sure these are not required on form submission. If yes, you probably get stuck on the same page but are not given any output because the fields errors are not displayed.

You can debug this by disabling the javascript on the radio field and showing field errors for each field.

Hope this could help.